# Compute the size of an array that was passed as a parameter to a function

Tags: array, functions

When passing an array to a function, you usually pass the length of the array along with it. You can compute the size of the array with `sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0])`, which works just fine.

However, if you try to do this within the function that you pass the array to, this doesn't return the length of the array - eg. if it is an `int` array, it returns 1, if it is a `double` array, it returns 0.

Why is that so and is there any way to compute the size of an array that was passed as a parameter?

Comment: If you don't use it often (every different type/size makes new instantiation od f function), then you can use templates like: `template <typename T, size_t N> void f(T(& myArray)[N])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You are passing a *pointer* to the array, and `sizeof` will give you the size of that pointer (2 on an 8-bit Arduino).

Instead the normal way is to pass the size of the array as a parameter to your function.

```
myFunction(myArray, sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]));
```